# How can I set the menu font in GRUB 2?

Tags: fonts, grub, grub2

I've just been forcibly upgraded to Grub 2, and I'm having trouble because the fonts in the GRUB menu are ugly and small.  I have successfully set the screen resolution with

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1200x32
```

in my `/etc/grub/default` file, and I attempted to set the font with

```
GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub/DejaVuSansMono48.pf2
```

where I created the font in question using `grub-mkfont`.

The native resolution works great, but unfortunately the font does not.  I'm thinking maybe this affects the font that is used once the OS boots, but it definitely does *not* affect the font on the GRUB boot menu.

**How can I get a larger font on the GRUB boot menu??**